# What if the Lagrangian density $\mathscr{L}$, instead of a Lorentz scalar, were a Lorentz vector?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, covariance, classical-field-theory

---

As an answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282534/) post, I made an impression that if $\mathscr{L}$ were not a Lorentz scalar in Eq.$(1)$ (see below), then Eq.$(1)$ would not be covariant. But now I think that is wrong! I state the reason below why I think so. If confirmed, I will delete the answer there.

---

**EDITED ON $14.04.23$**

The Euler-Lagrange equation for a field $\phi_a$ ($a=1,2,3,...N$ counts that number of components that mix under Lorentz transformation) given by $$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial\phi_a}=\partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi_a)}\right)\tag{1}$$ becomes $$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial\phi^\prime_a}=\partial_\mu^\prime\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial(\partial^\prime_\mu\phi^\prime_a)}\right)\tag{2}$$ where $\phi^\prime_a=S_{ab}\phi_b$ denotes the transformation of the field $\phi_a$ under Lorentz transformation. As far as the $\mu$ index is concerned, those are contracted and should not change. Also, since $\mathscr{L}$ is a Lorentz scalar, that too doesn't change. Therefore, the covariance of $(1)$ is manifest! So it satisfies the postulate of special relativity.

Now consider a different equation that has nothing to do with anything familiar! Write an equation by replacing $\mathscr{L}$ in $(2)$ with a quantity that has one uncontracted Lorentz index (say, $\mathscr{L}_\alpha$) : $$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}_\alpha}{\partial\phi_a}=\partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}_\alpha}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi_a)}\right)\tag{3}$$

**Question** As far as covariance is concerned, wouldn't equations of the form $(3)$ also be covariant?

If yes, it would be incorrect to say: "*if $\mathscr{L}$ were **not** a Lorentz scalar but a Lorentz vector $\mathscr{L}_\alpha$, equation of motions would **not** be covariant.*" In other words, the covariance of the equation of motion does not require $\mathscr{L}$ to be a Lorentz scalar. Is this correct?

Comment: I believe the issue is with the action then. I mean, if you integrate the "vector lagrangian" componentwise you would have be a problem since in practice you would be summing up vectors at different tangent spaces, and you would get basis dependent results I believe. Now if you contracted the vector with a covector before integrating, well the the integrand is a scalar and you are back to the old story. That is my point of view on this right now.

Comment: I see. My point is that the reason why $\mathscr{L}$ cannot be a Lorentz vector *cannot* be argued by saying that "if it were so, Eq. $(1)$ would not be covariant." Is that part agreable? @user1620696

Comment: That equation is not covariant in curved spacetime. But anyway, in flat spacetime you don't actually care whether $\mathcal{F}$ is a vector; you just have a bunch of actions, and require all of them to be extremized at the same time.

Comment: I have the suspicion that this would be possible for a large class of Equations Of Motion, but the nice thing about Lagrangians is the fact that they *aren't* vectors, but scalars. Lagrangians provide a compact, frame independent way of writing EOM. So why would we want a covariant Largrangian when we could just as easily write down the equations of motion?

Comment: @AndrewSteane Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion As I said in the opening sentence that previously I wrote an answer on this site claiming that the Lagrangian density must be Lorentz scalar for equations of motion to be covariant. But on further thought, I found that this need not be the case; any tensor Lagrangian is fine as long as the covariance of the equation of motion is concerned. I just wanted to be sure. Maybe symmetry, Noether's theorem, etc may not hold in their original form or may not be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of using a scalar Lagrangian is not necessarily obvious from classical physics in flat space-time. The point is that

- The [Hamilton's principle of least action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle) has proven to be an extremely useful tool to analyse the symmetries of a physical theory and thus also its conservation laws through [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). For example, writing down a scalar Lagrangian with coordinate invariance immediately provides us with tools to analyze the conservation of momentum and energy (and what momentum and energy even *are* in the theory). A multi-component object makes this much less clear.
- Hamilton's action $S = \int_{\Omega} \mathcal{L} d^4 V$ is typically just a single number associated with the entire space-time domain $\Omega$. If you integrate a multi-component object over the space-time domain, you get a dangling index on $S$, $S^a = \int \mathcal{L}^a d^4 V$. This index must correspond to a "global" coordinate system or gauge group basis over the entire domain $\Omega$ somehow. This is in violation with *local* [gauge invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory) on which the entirety of the Standard model of particle physics and *local* [diffeomorphism invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_covariance) on which General Relativity is built. (Local diffeomorphism covariance and/or invariance is the statement that your action principle and physical laws need have the same form irrespective of the coordinate system used, including curvi-linear coordinates, not just global Cartesian-Minkowski coordinates.)  *This is the point most relevant to the main body of your question.*
- The vanishing variation $\delta S^a/\delta \phi = 0$ gives you more than one equation $\phi$ has to fulfill. Unless you make the functional $S^a$ (or the function $\mathcal{L}^a$) somehow degenerate, you will often get overconstrained systems. If you make $S^a$ degenerate, you will often find the corresponding Lagrangian can be "contracted'' or traced out into a scalar.
- Perhaps not as importantly, the [path-integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) would have great difficulties with a non-scalar action in expressions such as the transition amplitdue $\propto e^{i S/\hbar}$. How to do this with a multi-component object? And if you find a way, why don't you call the resulting scalar $\mathcal{S}(S^a)$ showing up in the transition amplitude $\propto e^{i\mathcal{S}(S^a)/\hbar}$ the action instead of the set $S^a$? This is just one other illustration how deeply the scalar Lagrangian and action are embedded into fundamental theories of physics.

---

This is not to say that it is somehow *forbidden* to try and develop multi-component Lagrangian-like structures. It is interesting to imagine what could be the contexts where it is useful, such as when a medium defines some sort of global coordinates providing a basis for the dangling index $a$ etc. But in physics rather than mathematics you must ***justify*** the use of a generalized structure in a real physical context, not just postulate it arbitrarily. And unless the structure is justified by its usefulness, it is just met with a shoulder shrug.

This is because once you ask about multi-component Lagrangians, you do not need to stop there. You can start building theories that are not generated by *any* Lagrangian-like structure whatsoever. The field equations can just have objects in them that have the correct transformation properties. Why not, right? Or they can have objects in them that are a function of more than one space-time points. Or they can have objects in them that have a different meaning depending on the time of the day. Why not? The important question is why yes.

**TL;DR:** Modern fundamental physics such as general relativity, quantum mechanics, or quantum field theory are built around scalar actions and Lagrangians, and vector Lagrangians pose complications with no obvious advantage. Until there is no advantage in using them, you are not forbidden to try to develop use cases, but nobody will necessarily care.

Answer (score 4):

I believe at least in flat spacetime, such things make sense. At the very least, Doran, Lasenby and Gull [have studied](http://geometry.mrao.cam.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Poland93_GrassmannMech.pdf) even further generalized Lagrangians, namely multi-vector Lagrangians in the setting of geometric algebra. As for the specific case of vector (or tensor) valued Lagrangians in relativistic field theory, they do indeed give sensible covariant equations of motion, with tensor rank equal to or higher than the Lagrangian itself. As a simple example, lets consider a vector valued Lagrangian coupling a scalar field $\phi$ to a vector field $\psi^a$,

$$
\mathcal{L}^a = m \phi \psi^a  + \partial^a \phi \partial_b \psi^b
$$
This Lagrangian density is clearly a Lorentz vector. Now let us take the variation first with respect to $\phi$:

$$
\delta \mathcal{L}^a = m \delta \phi \psi^a + \partial^a \delta\phi \partial_b \psi^b =0
$$
Doing the usual partial integration of the second term and dropping surface terms gives
$$
m \delta \phi \psi^a - \delta\phi\partial^a  \partial_b \psi^b =0,
$$
so our Euler Lagrange equation becomes
$$
m \psi^a - \partial^a\partial_b \psi^b=0,
$$
which is a perfectly sensible covariant equation of motion.

Similarly, let us take the variation with respect to $\psi^a$,
$$
\delta \mathcal{L}^a = m \phi \delta\psi^a + \partial^a \phi \partial_b \delta\psi^b =0
$$
Doing the usual partial integration gives
$$
m \phi \delta\psi^a - \delta\psi^b\partial_b \partial^a \phi  =0
$$
We can write this as
$$
(m \phi \delta^a_b - \partial_b \partial^a \phi )\delta\psi^b =0
$$
So our Euler-Lagrange equation is
$$
m \phi \delta^a_b - \partial_b \partial^a \phi =0 
$$
This is once again a covariant equation of motion.

As for the curved spacetime generalization, that I'm not sure if its still sensible, but perhaps a generalization in terms of tetrads or such could be done. Someone who's more familiar with Lagrangian field theories on curved spacetimes could chip in here.

Comment: In the equation of motion of $\psi^a$, i.e. $
m \,\phi \,\delta^a_b - \partial_b \partial^a \phi =0 
$, the first term has the Kronecker delta function $\delta^a_b$ which is not a Lorentz tensor and hence not covariant. The second term, i.e. $\partial_b \partial^a \phi$, transforms as a (1,1) tensor under Lorentz transformations. So it seems that the full equation of motion is not covariant.

Comment: The Kronecker delta is a tensor, just a special one. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerDelta.html for instance

Comment: I said in my previous comment that the Kronecker delta function is not a Lorentz tensor and hence not covariant.

Comment: Yes and that was incorrect

Comment: No, the equation is covariant since all quantities in the equation are (1,1) tensors. You seem to be confused, in that you do not think the kronecker delta is a (1,1) tensor. This is incorrect. By definition it's the identity mapping from the targent space to itself, and this is by construction a (1,1) tensor.

Comment: In that case you are in disagreement with most differential geometry textbooks and materials

Comment: @vyali See [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/215388/50583) for a discussion of the tensorial properties of $\delta$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind that's a great answer

Comment: If your spacetime is a contractile manifold then I think it can be generalized to curved spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the covariance of the equations of motion does not require the Lagrangian density to be a Lorentz scalar, as shown in the example you provided. However, this is a rather unusual case and does not necessarily apply to physical theories.

In general, physical theories are formulated using Lagrangians that are Lorentz scalars. This is because Lorentz invariance is a fundamental symmetry of spacetime in special relativity, and physical observables should not depend on the choice of reference frame. By constructing a Lagrangian density that is a Lorentz scalar, we ensure that the action is invariant under Lorentz transformations, and the resulting equations of motion are covariant. This guarantees that the physical predictions of the theory are frame-independent.

In the example you provided with a Lagrangian density having one uncontracted Lorentz index, the equations of motion appear to be covariant. However, this does not necessarily mean that such a Lagrangian density would lead to a physically meaningful theory. It is possible that the resulting theory may not be consistent with the principles of special relativity or have other undesirable properties.

It is true that the covariance of the equations of motion does not require the Lagrangian density to be a Lorentz scalar, using a Lorentz scalar Lagrangian density is the standard approach in formulating physical theories consistent with special relativity. The example you provided demonstrates an unusual case and may not necessarily lead to a meaningful physical theory.

To answer your question, yes, your understanding is correct. Equations of the form (3) can also be covariant, even if the Lagrangian density is not a Lorentz scalar but a Lorentz vector. So, it would be incorrect to say that if the Lagrangian density were not a Lorentz scalar but a Lorentz vector, the equations of motion would not be covariant.

Comment: Plenty of physical theories depend on the reference frame. I.e. they break Lorentz invariance / principles of special relativity. They just aren't *microscopic* theories.

Comment: _"It is possible that the resulting theory may not be consistent with the principles of special relativity or have other undesirable properties."_ Do you have anything concrete in mind? I think, symmetry, Noether's theorem, etc may not hold in their original form or may not be useful.

Comment: @SRS intuitively, I would consider the Chern-Simons Lagrangian density in (2+1)-dimensional space-time.

Answer (score 1):

Lagrangian density is scalar because of the equation

$$S[\phi_i]=\int \mathcal{L}(\phi_i,\partial _\mu\phi_i, \mathbf{x}) d^4\mathbf{x}$$

Since the action is a scalar quantity you can't get a scalar by adding (integration) a bunch of vector,

Under Lorentz transformation or any other type of linear transformation of coordinate system, quantities such as scalars, vectors or higher order tensors remains invariant. (Things doesn't change just because one is trying to look at it from a different frame of reference), The components will differ in accordance to your basis, ( the length number may change if you started measuring in feet instead of meter, but length of object will never change, basis or coordinate system is like choosing meter or feet, while components are value associated with it ) but all such things remains invariant under any linear transformation, with coordinates transformation the new components comes out to be in accordance to your transformation rule, which is known as covariance.

So if there were some 'vector action' type thing with an associated vector lagrangian, sure we could have a 'vector lagrangian',

Edit:

Action is basically a functional that takes path(functions) $q_i(t)$ and gives a scalar quantity with it according to equation above,

The action principle says 'extremizing this action will give you a optimum path that a system will follow between two points in a configuration space,

However if one were to use a vector action, then it would be tedious to find extremums, as vectors are not like scalar that can be compared directly (loosely speaking, as scalars of different spaces can't be compared without any pull back or push forward map).(this part is to be taken loosely)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite stumped that this is not yet solved satisfactorily.

Yes, it is true that Euler-Lagrange equations allow us to consider Lagrangian densities that are Lorentz covariant, not needing them to be exactly a scalar.

However, a bit of thought shows that the Lagrangian densities can only be scalar, pseudo-scalar, or even ranked tensors of special type. Maybe a mix of the former two might be a way to generate matter-anti-matter assymmetry, but otherwise it can only be one or the other.

This is because Lagrangian densities are integrated over all of spacetime *and* exponentiated. If the Lagrangian densities has any unpaired Lorentz covariant index, then the exponentiation causes ever increasing complications. If the Lorentz covariant index is contracted away, then either it is contracted with a privileged tensor, or it is contracted with itself. The former case is rejected by the lack of privileged directions, and the latter case reduces back to scalar or pseudo-scalars. This is also related to how the action S = integrated Lagrangian density must not be dimension-full (after dividing by hbar).

Notice, however, it can be a square matrix, or a Lie algebra element. i.e. things that can be applied to themselves infinitely many times and still make sense. If it is to be a tensor, it must have equal numbers of contravariant indices and covariant indices with a natural way to pair them. It is however, not very clear what the physical interpretation of these things could be. Maybe someone in the future could make a sensible theory out of such exotic stuff. (Connecting with AwkwardWhale's answer, the even subalgebra of a geometric algebra is possible.)

Comment: You don't need exponentiation to make this point. Just say there is one time => one generator of time translations => one Legendre transformation of it. With many time co-ordinates, you could define exponentiation component-wise.

Comment: @ConnorBehan You are wrong. Nowhere did OP nor my answer talk about more than one generator of time translations or more than one Legendre transformations, or more than one time coördinate. Having a Lagrangian density that isn't one of the stuff I left possible, has nothing to do with more than one time coördinate either.

Comment: The fact that you didn't talk about it is precisely my point. One time co-ordinate implies at most one Lagrangian by definition. If there are two functionals whose extremizations yield equations which hold in your system, then at least one of them is not the Lagrangian and therefore the ability to exponentiate it is an extra postulate being pulled out of a hat.

Comment: @ConnorBehan No. Having the Lagrangian density be multi-component does not imply that there will be more than one Lagrangian at work. Either you prove it is so, or cease. In both cases, you should be working it out in a bigger solution, not commenting on this thread.

Comment: A quantity and its density have the same number of components. A mod can move this comment if it's truly in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

An equation is said to be Lorentz covariant if it can be written in terms of Lorentz covariant quantities. A physical quantity is said to be Lorentz covariant if it transforms under a given representation of the Lorentz group. A Lorentz covariant scalar (e.g., the space-time interval) remains the same under Lorentz transformations and is said to be a Lorentz invariant.

Therefore, the covariance of the equation of motion does not require L to be a Lorentz scalar, but it does require L to be a Lorentz covariant quantity. For example, the wave equation ∂^2 ϕ ∂ x^2 = c^2 ∂^2 ϕ ∂ t^2 is Lorentz covariant, but ϕ is not a Lorentz scalar, it is a scalar field that transforms as a scalar under Lorentz transformations

Comment: *"but ϕ is not a Lorentz scalar, it is a scalar field that transforms as a scalar under Lorentz transformations"*...what does this mean?

Comment: This means that ϕ is not just a number, but a function of space and time that assigns a number to each point in spacetime. However, this number does not change under Lorentz transformations, which means that ϕ is invariant under any change of inertial frame