# Help in proof: Lorentz invariant Lagrangians lead to Lorentz covariant equations

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, mathematics, covariance

I think that the following statement is true, but can't seem to prove it.

Suppose we have a scalar field whose Lagrangian density$^1$ $\mathcal L(\phi, ~\partial_\mu\phi, ~X^\mu)$ is Lorentz invariant. By this I mean that $\mathcal L(\phi, ~\partial_\mu\phi, ~X^\mu)=\mathcal L(\phi, ~\Lambda_\mu^{\;\;\nu}~\partial_\nu\phi, ~\Lambda^\mu_{\;\;\nu}~X^\nu)$ for any arbitrary proper Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$. Then the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$
{\partial\mathcal L\over\partial\phi} = \partial_\mu{\partial\mathcal L\over\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}
$$
are Lorentz covariant.

Can you help me prove it? Or is it false?

---

1. The action is therefore $\int \mathcal L~~dt~dx~dy~dz$. Note that the space-time volume element $dt~dx~dy~dz$ is Lorentz invariant since $\det(\Lambda) = 1$ (proper transformations). So if $\mathcal L$ is Lorentz invariant too, then the action is also Lorentz invariant.

Comment: This is a special case of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144389/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: @Qmechanic You are a *savior*! Since you seem to have an enormous knowledge of such stuff, can you maybe recommend some of your favorite resources on this subject?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I am not familiar with the mathematical machinery that you use there... So can you at least just a definitive yes/no answer whether my proposition is correct?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506259/what-if-the-lagrangian-mathscrl-a-lorentz-scalar-is-replaced-by-a-lorentz